# Snake program in java.Why i get a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Here's the code of RenderPanel: it throws somewhy a nullpointerExcepiton and i dont know why. It says the problem with the for each Cycle in RenderPanel class.

```
 public class RenderPanel extends JPanel {

public static Color green = new Color(6750054);

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Snake snake = Snake.snake;
    g.setColor(green);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 700, 600);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for(Point point : snake.snakeParts){
        g.fillRect(point.x * Snake.SCALE,point.y * Snake.SCALE, Snake.SCALE, Snake.SCALE);
    }
    g.fillRect(snake.head.x * Snake.SCALE, snake.head.y * Snake.SCALE, Snake.SCALE, Snake.SCALE);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(snake.cherry.x * Snake.SCALE, snake.cherry.y * Snake.SCALE, Snake.SCALE, Snake.SCALE);
    String string = "Score: " + snake.score + ", Length: " + snake.tailLength + ", Time: " + snake.time / 20;
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString(string, (int) (getWidth() / 2 - string.length() * 2.5f), 10);
    string = "Game Over!";
    if (snake.gameOver){
        g.drawString(string, (int) (getWidth() / 2 - string.length() * 2.5f), (int) snake.dim.getHeight() / 4);
    }
    string = "Paused!";

    if (snake.paused && !snake.gameOver){
        g.drawString(string, (int) (getWidth() / 2 - string.length() * 2.5f), (int) snake.dim.getHeight() / 4);
    }
}



}
```

And the code of the snake program:

```
 public class Snake implements ActionListener,KeyListener {

public static Snake snake;
JFrame jframe;
public Dimension dim;
public RenderPanel renderPanel;
public Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
public ArrayList<Point> snakeParts = new ArrayList<Point>();
public static final int UP = 0, DOWN = 1, LEFT = 2, RIGHT = 3, SCALE = 10;
public int ticks = 0, direction = DOWN, score, tailLength = 10, time;
public Point head, cherry;
public Random random;
public boolean gameOver = false, paused;




 public Snake(){
    jframe = new JFrame();
    dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    jframe.setTitle("Snake");
    jframe.add( renderPanel = new RenderPanel());
    jframe.setSize(705, 600);
    jframe.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - jframe.getWidth() /2, dim.height / 2 - jframe.getHeight() / 2);
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
    jframe.setResizable(false);
    jframe.addKeyListener(this);
    startGame();

 }

 public void startGame(){
    gameOver = false;
    paused = false;
    time = 0;
    score = 0;
    tailLength = 14;
    ticks = 0;
    direction = DOWN;
    head = new Point(0,-1);
    random = new Random();
    snakeParts.clear();
    cherry = new Point(random.nextInt(79), random.nextInt(66));
 }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    renderPanel.repaint();
    ticks++;

    if(ticks % 2 == 0 && head != null && !gameOver && !paused ){
    time++;

    snakeParts.add(new Point(head.x,head.y));

    if(direction == UP){
        if(head.y - 1 > 0 && noTailAt(head.x, head.y -1)){
            head = new Point(head.x,head.y-1);
        }else{
            gameOver = true;
        }

    }


    if (direction == DOWN){

         if (head.y + 1 < 67 && noTailAt(head.x, head.y + 1)){

            head = new Point(head.x, head.y + 1);
        }else{
            gameOver = true;
                    }
                }

    if(direction == LEFT){
        if(head.x - 1 > 0 && noTailAt(head.x - 1, head.y)){
            head = new Point(head.x - 1,head.y);
        }else{
            gameOver = true;
        }

    }

    if (direction == DOWN){

         if (head.x + 1 < 80 && noTailAt(head.x, head.y + 1)){

            head = new Point(head.x + 1, head.y);
        }else{
            gameOver = true;
                    }
                }

    if (snakeParts.size() > tailLength) {
        snakeParts.remove(0);
    }
    if(cherry != null){

        if(head.equals(cherry)){
            score+=10;
            tailLength++;
            cherry.setLocation(random.nextInt(79), random.nextInt(66));
        }
    }

          }

     }

 public boolean noTailAt(int x , int y){
    for(Point point : snakeParts){
        if(point.equals(new Point(x,y))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
    Snake snake = new Snake();
 }
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: What line is it throwing a null pointer at ?

Comment: RenderPanel Class -> for(Point point : snake.snakeParts){...-> " Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at othersna.RenderPanel.paintComponent(RenderPanel.java:21)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)"

Comment: snake is null. Thats is why you get a null pointer.

Comment: Exactly where? What should i do to not get the message? (Sorry, i'm a beginner)

Comment: I am trying to figure out. Did u follow any tutorial to built it

Comment: Dude i figured out that place where you copied it from . Copy it correctly it works or me

Comment: Yes, i wrote the code based on a video tutorial, but i wrote all the code myself.In other hand I tried to copy-paste the original code, but that's neither working to me. The same error, in the same line. :/

Comment: ask the question again , I can give you the code.